# Using dynamic parameters in Web API methods

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, dynamic, json.net

I'm working on a Web API project and using Massive to do database tasks.
In my controllers I want Post methods accept a dynamic object so it can be used by Massive `Insert` method directly.

```
public class LinkController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(dynamic link)
    {
        dynamic model = new Massive.DynamicModel("main", tableName: "Links", primaryKeyField: "Id");
        return Ok(model.Insert(link));
    }
}
```

And in the POST request the following JSON is sent:

```
{
    "Name":"StackOverflow",
    "Url":"http://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "Description":"My most visited web site!",
    "FolderId":2
}
```

My problem is the way JSON.Net deserializes JSONs. When the `Post` method is called, link parameter has 4 properties as expected
but they are of type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue not some primitive types (for expample string for Name) and Massive cannot
handle JValue objects.

I need to force the parameter to have primitive types for its properties (by creating a custom JsonConverter, tweaking Web API model bindings, ...).

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is deserializing your DTOs into `ExpandoObject`:

```
// config.GetType() == typeof(HttpConfiguration)
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

It's still a dynamic object while you access its properties as it they were designed in a regular class with .NET CLR types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that but unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: @FarzanHajian This is impossible as this is how I'm configuring some of my own WebAPIs to get this working...